# Maven including multiple versions of spring dependencies

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

I have this project that I am trying to get to run. Tomcat is having a issues but I noticed that I have multiple versions of spring packages and I cannot figure out where the spring 3.2.2 jars are coming from.

** EDIT I unzipped the war on the server and removed the 3.2.2 jars and rezipped the war and deployed it and its working. So the issue is for sure the 3.2.2 jars.

When I searched for the issue people suggested to use Spring 4 which i thought i was using

i am building with

```
mvn package -f rest/pom.xml assembly:single
```

Parent pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>com.riskpass.aml</groupId>
    <artifactId>riskpass-aml-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>RiskPass AML Parent</name>
    <version>0.7.0</version>

    <properties>
        <glassfish.javax.servlet.version>3.1.1</glassfish.javax.servlet.version>
        <jetty.version>9.3.3.v20150827</jetty.version>
        <querydsl.version>3.6.7</querydsl.version>
        <springframework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>

        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>batch</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>rest</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.autentia.web.rest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wadl-zipper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <port>9090</port>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.36</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                <version>4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.javax.servlet.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
                <version>1.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
                <artifactId>config</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.53.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.01</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I added the version to the children poms

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.riskpass.aml</groupId>
        <artifactId>riskpass-aml-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>riskpass-aml-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>RiskPass AML REST</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.riskpass.aml</groupId>
            <artifactId>riskpass-aml-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.autentia</groupId>
            <artifactId>wadl-tools</artifactId>
            <version>wadl-tools-1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.76/webapps/riskpass-java/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.76/webapps/riskpass-java/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
        SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My war

[image]

Maven dependency tree has NOTHING referring to 3.2.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full `pom.xml` file (and the parent `pom.xml` files). Also add the maven command you used to build the `war` file. Basically, provide a [mcve], which reproduce the error.

Comment: @Progman added those poms and command

Comment: Mixing different versions of spring framework.. also using ancient old versions of dependencies and plugins etc...

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` will show you any dependency conflicts and most probably the overwritten version of the jar that you are missing in the above report.

Answer (score 0):

As @marinos-an pointed out, verbose showed the conflicts `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. I just removed that package and the code that used it

```
[INFO] +- com.github.autentia:wadl-tools:jar:wadl-tools-1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.autentia.wadl-tools:spring-wadl-generator:jar:wadl-tools-1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - version managed from 2.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.2.2.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
```